# キーがユニークでないDataFrameをunstackする方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

PandasのDataFrameを、unstackしたいのですが、
エラー「ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape」が発生し困っています。
エラーメッセージより、unstackするDataFrameは、unstack後のインデックスがユニークでないといけないようなのです。
以下のような、データ変換をしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいか、教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [10, 100],
        [20, 200],
        [30, 300],
        [40, 400],
    ],
    index=[
        ['埼玉', '埼玉', '東京', '東京'],
        ['タイプA', 'タイプB', 'タイプC', 'タイプC'],  # ←キーが重複しているとエラーが発生しunstackできないようです。
        # ['タイプA', 'タイプB', 'タイプB', 'タイプC'],  # ←正しくunstackできました。
    ],
    columns=[
        ['値１', '値２'],
    ]
)
print('【入力】')
display(df)

df = df.unstack(level=0)
df = df.swaplevel(axis='columns').sort_index(axis='columns')
display(df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーメッセージ

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 30
     27 print('【入力】')
     28 display(df)
---> 30 df = df.unstack(level=0)
     31 df = df.swaplevel(axis='columns').sort_index(axis='columns')
     32 display(df)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:8961, in DataFrame.unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   8899 """
   8900 Pivot a level of the (necessarily hierarchical) index labels.
   8901 
   (...)
   8957 dtype: float64
   8958 """
   8959 from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
-> 8961 result = unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   8963 return result.__finalize__(self, method="unstack")

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py:475, in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    473 if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):
    474     if isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex):
--> 475         return _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value)
    476     else:
    477         return obj.T.stack(dropna=False)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py:498, in _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value)
    496 def _unstack_frame(obj: DataFrame, level, fill_value=None):
    497     assert isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex)  # checked by caller
--> 498     unstacker = _Unstacker(obj.index, level=level, constructor=obj._constructor)
    500     if not obj._can_fast_transpose:
    501         mgr = obj._mgr.unstack(unstacker, fill_value=fill_value)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py:136, in _Unstacker.__init__(self, index, level, constructor)
    128 if num_cells > np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
    129     warnings.warn(
    130         f"The following operation may generate {num_cells} cells "
    131         f"in the resulting pandas object.",
    132         PerformanceWarning,
    133         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    134     )
--> 136 self._make_selectors()

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py:188, in _Unstacker._make_selectors(self)
    185 mask.put(selector, True)
    187 if mask.sum() < len(self.index):
--> 188     raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
    190 self.group_index = comp_index
    191 self.mask = mask

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

以下は、期待する結果です。

```
# 期待する結果
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [np.nan, np.nan, 10, 100],
        [np.nan, np.nan, 20, 200],
        [30, 300, np.nan, np.nan],
        [40, 400, np.nan, np.nan],
    ],
    index=['タイプA', 'タイプB', 'タイプC', 'タイプC'],
    columns=[
        ['埼玉', '埼玉', '東京', '東京'],
        ['値１', '値２', '値１', '値２'],
    ]
)
print('【期待する結果】')
display(df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = df.T.groupby(df.index, axis=1).sum().T
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)

df = df.unstack(level=0)
df = df.swaplevel(axis='columns').sort_index(axis='columns')

#          埼玉         東京       
#          値１   値２   値１    値２
# タイプA  10.0  100.0   NaN    NaN
# タイプB  20.0  200.0   NaN    NaN
# タイプC   NaN    NaN  70.0  700.0
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。groupbyで集計（合計）し、unstackする前のインデックスをユニークにする必要があるということですね。